# Heroku breaks when precompiling assets. with "rake aborted! Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

When pushing to heroku, using a cleardb mysql db, heroku breaks when precompiling assets.

1. I've added 
   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false 
   to my application.rb file.
2. Its also in my enviroment/staging.rb & production.rb file.
3. I've added the cleardb url to DATABSE_URL config variable as mysql2 url.

I have a staging environment that I can push just fine, dont understand what is going on

Ive added the heroku output below:

```
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)


    /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql20.3.13/lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:    in `connect'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block(2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block
in checkout'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checko
ut'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block
in connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connec
tion'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrie
ve_connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:i
n `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:i
n `connection'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/
lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2258599545640707426__prepare__376
3978473180365505__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/
rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/li
b/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:101:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_ure0m4wsxy41/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rak
e/application.rb:70:in `run'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting

-----> WARNINGS:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> web
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 59.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v17
-----> Deploy hooks scheduled, check output in your logs
       http://acadmx-staging-two.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:acadmx-staging-two.git
   e0d337d..1f9808f  production -> master
Andrew@ANDREW-T520 ~/Documents/Projects/Acadmx/src/acadmx_web (production)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application initializes (Rails does in some scenarios) a connection to the database during it's boot stage you run into this problem when compiling assets in production.

You need to give your application access to environment variables via a Heroku labs feature

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

You can read more about this at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: Seemed to happen to me when deploying a Rails Admin application on Rails 4. But this solves the problem :).